# Hibernate table doesn't exist

Tags: database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

When I test my project, just 4 tables are created in the database but not the others and I do not know why. The tables `notification`, `position`, `dernierePosition` and `user` are created but not the table `demande` and other tables that I didn't put in this example. There are some properties that i forgot?
Thanks for your help.
Here are some files:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <!-- Database connection settings, Connect to HSQL, IN Memory  -->
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/***</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
  <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) 
 List of XML mapping files -->
  <mapping class="modele.Demande" resource="Demande.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.DernierePosition" resource="DernierePosition.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.Group" resource="Group.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.Invitation" resource="Invitation.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.Marqueur" resource="Marqueur.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.Notification" resource="Notification.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.NotificationMarqueur" resource="NotificationMarqueur.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.Position" resource="Position.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping class="modele.User" resource="User.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Position.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 15 févr. 2014 01:46:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="modele.Position" table="POSITION">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="lattitude" type="double">
            <column name="LATTITUDE" />
        </property>
        <property name="longitude" type="double">
            <column name="LONGITUDE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**DenierePosition.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 15 févr. 2014 01:46:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <joined-subclass name="modele.DernierePosition" extends="modele.Position" table="DERNIEREPOSITION" lazy="false">
        <key>
            <column name="ID" />
        </key>
        <property name="time" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="TIME" />
        </property>
        <one-to-one name="user" class="modele.User"></one-to-one>
    </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Notification.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 15 févr. 2014 01:46:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="modele.Notification" table="NOTIFICATION">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="user" class="modele.User" fetch="join">
            <column name="USER" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Demande.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Demande extends Notification {

    private Group group;

    private User demandeur;

    public Demande(){

    }

    public Demande(Group group, User demandeur) {
        super(group.getProprietaire());
        this.group = group;
        this.demandeur=demandeur;
    }

    // Getters and setters


}
```

**Demande.hbm.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated 15 févr. 2014 01:46:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <joined-subclass name="modele.Demande" extends="modele.Notification" table="DEMANDE" lazy="false">
        <key>
            <column name="ID" />
        </key>
        <many-to-one name="group" class="modele.Group" fetch="join">
            <column name="GROUP" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="demandeur" class="modele.User" fetch="join">
            <column name="DEMANDEUR" />
        </many-to-one>
    </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**User.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {

    /** Attributs */ 

    private int id;

    private String pseudo;

    private String telephone;

    private String email;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Demande> demandes;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Invitation> aInvite;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Notification> notifications;

    private DernierePosition dernierePosition;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Group> groups;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Group> proprietaire;

    /** Constructeur */ 
    public User() {
    }

    public User(String telephone, String pseudo, String email) {
        super();
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.email = email;
    }
// Getters and setters
}
```

**User.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 15 févr. 2014 01:46:28 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="modele.User" table="USER">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="pseudo" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PSEUDO" />
        </property>
        <property name="telephone" type="java.lang.String" not-null="true" unique="true">
            <column name="TELEPHONE" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="EMAIL" />
        </property>
        <set name="demandes" table="DEMANDE" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.Demande" />
        </set>
        <set name="aInvite" table="INVITATION" inverse="false" lazy="true" access="field">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.Invitation" />
        </set>
        <set name="notifications" table="NOTIFICATION" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.Notification" />
        </set>
        <one-to-one name="dernierePosition" class="modele.DernierePosition"></one-to-one>
        <set name="groups" table="GROUP" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.Group" />
        </set>
        <set name="proprietaire" table="GROUP" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.Group" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Group.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Group {

    /** Attributs */

    private int id;

    private String description;

    private String hashtag;

    private String password;

    private Set<Marqueur> marqueurs;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Invitation> invitations;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Demande> demandes;

    private User proprietaire;

    private Set<User> invites;

    /** 
     * Constructeur 
     * */ 
    public Group()
    {

    }

    public Group(String description, String hashtag, User proprietaire, String password) {
        super();
        this.description = description;
        this.hashtag = hashtag;
        this.proprietaire = proprietaire;
        this.setPassword(password);
    }
```

**Group.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 16 f?vr. 2014 11:30:30 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="modele.Group" table="GROUP">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" />
        </property>
        <property name="hashtag" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="HASHTAG" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="PASSWORD" />
        </property>
        <set name="marqueurs" table="MARQUEUR" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.Marqueur" />
        </set>
        <set name="invitations" table="INVITATION" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.Invitation" />
        </set>
        <many-to-one name="proprietaire" class="modele.User" fetch="join">
            <column name="PROPRIETAIRE" />
        </many-to-one>
        <set name="invites" table="USER" inverse="false" lazy="true">
            <key>
                <column name="ID" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="modele.User" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Test User**

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import modele.User;

import org.junit.Test;


public class UserDaoTest {

    private final String tel = "0601020304";
    private final String pseudo = "pseudo";
    private final String pseudoModified = "pseudo2";
    private final String email = "email@email.com";

    @Test
    public void addUserTest(){

        User initialUser = new User(tel, pseudo, email);

        UserDao.addUser(initialUser);

        User addedUser = UserDao.getUser(tel);

        Assert.assertEquals(addedUser.getTelephone(), initialUser.getTelephone());
        Assert.assertEquals(addedUser.getPseudo(), initialUser.getPseudo());
        Assert.assertEquals(addedUser.getEmail(), initialUser.getEmail());
    }

    @Test
    public void modifyUserTest(){
        UserDao.modifyUser(tel, pseudoModified, email);

        User modifiedUser = UserDao.getUser(tel);

        Assert.assertEquals(modifiedUser.getTelephone(), tel);
        Assert.assertEquals(modifiedUser.getPseudo(), pseudoModified);
        Assert.assertEquals(modifiedUser.getEmail(), email);

    }

    @Test
    public void listUserTest(){
        User modifiedUser = UserDao.getUser(tel);

        List<User> listUsers = UserDao.listUser();

        User listedUser = listUsers.get(listUsers.indexOf(modifiedUser));

        Assert.assertEquals(listedUser.getTelephone(), modifiedUser.getTelephone());
        Assert.assertEquals(listedUser.getPseudo(), modifiedUser.getPseudo());
        Assert.assertEquals(listedUser.getEmail(), modifiedUser.getEmail());
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteUserTest(){
        User user = UserDao.getUser(tel);

        UserDao.deleteUser(user.getTelephone());

        List<User> listUsers = UserDao.listUser();

        Assert.assertEquals(listUsers.indexOf(user), -1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there's a problem with many-to-one and joined-subclass.  It's explained in detail over on [the hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=932029); I'm not entirely clear on why it's the case, but the explanation from sdknott (on that site) is:

> The problem you have is with your mapping. By stating that your constraining column of the many-to-one is in fact your primary key column of table A, Hibernate will always try and resolve an entity B since the many-to-one column will never be empty.

I've used your source and changed the various `many-to-one` mappings in joined-subclasses to `one-to-one` mappings, and it all works for me now.  Hopefully that will allow you to express your schema correctly.

---

*(Aside) Original answer that didn't solve the problem*

I see that you have two members called "user" in the `Demande` class; remember that `Demande` is a subclass of `Notification` and gets its members.  I've never tried that and it looks odd, and it's definitely going to be confusing.  It might be what's causing your problem.

If you really want two "user" members, give them more suitable names (maybe "requester" and "responder"? Just guessing from the context).  If you only want one "user", then you don't need to put it in `Demande`, it's already in `Notification`.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted user in Demande but nothing changes. Group.xml does not also create a table in database

Comment: I put my project in UTF-8. It's ok now for the comments févr

Comment: Thanks your help. The problem is : that will change everything in my model if I put one-to-one everywhere. In my program, a user can have several demands, that will not be possible any more with a relation one to one? As well as a user can belong to several groups and a group can contain several users. I added class user, demand and group to my code.

Comment: Ah I see the problem.  You're worried that the one-to-many from `User` to `Notification` has to have an equivalent `many-to-one` from `Notification` to `User`.  Don't worry about this: it *doesn't* have to be bidirectional.  If the `Notification` doesn't *have* to know about the `User`, then it shouldn't; if it *has* to know about the `User`, then it's ok to make it a one-to-one mapping.  That *will not* affect the one-to-many mapping from `User` to `Notification`.  The same applies to all the other one-to-many mappings.

Comment: Thanks. I resolved this problem. I changed completely my hibernate xml files. I have other question if you can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852012/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails-hibernate